# PHP Regexp strtolower function that maintains case of text within quotes

Tags: php, regex

I search a method to get a lower string but does not change the case of text within quotes.

The string :

```
SELECT * FROM UtilisateurApplicatif WHERE idUtilisateurApplicatif <> "-1" AND Identification = "TOTO" AND MotDePasse = "TotoTUTU" AND Actif = 1
```

The result why i want :

```
select * from utilisateurapplicatif where idutilisateurapplicatif <> "-1" and identification = "TOTO" and motdepasse = "TotoTUTU" and actif = 1
```

Comment: May I ask why? MySQL is case insensetive.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you want the results to be lower case? You can use `strtolower()` then.

Comment: He wants to convert the input to lower case *except* for the parts in between quote marks.  I assume wants to preserve the case there.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using *preg_replace_callback* that allows to apply a function on a match result:

```
$subject = <<<'LOD'
SELECT * FROM UtilisateurApplicatif
WHERE idUtilisateurApplicatif <> "-1"
AND Identification = "TOTO"
AND MotDePasse = "Toto\"TUTU" AND Actif = 1
LOD;

$pattern = <<<'LOD'
~
(?(DEFINE) 
    (?<DQuotedContent>
        (?> [^"\\]++ | (?:\\{2})++ | \\. )*
    )
)
" \g<DQuotedContent> " \K | [A-Z]++
~x
LOD;

$result = preg_replace_callback($pattern,
    function ($match) { return strtolower($match[0]); },
    $subject);
print_r($result);
```

Pattern explanation:

The idea of the pattern is to match quoted parts before and remove them from the match result to not apply the *strtolower*.

First I define a subpattern (`DQuotedContent`) with all the possible content between double quotes, ie:

- all characters that are not a double quote or a backslash `[^"\\]`
- all even number of backslashes `(?:\\{2})++` (which can't escape anything)
- escaped characters (an escaped double quote can't close a quoted string)

The main part of the pattern is now easy to write:

```
" \g<DQuotedContent> "      # quoted part
\K                          # reset all that have been matched before
|                           # OR
[A-Z]++                     # uppercase letters
```

Note that the `\K` is very useful since it remove the quoted part from the match. Thus the callback function don't have to know what have been matched to apply *strtolower*.

Notice: I have written the pattern using the nowdoc syntax, a define section, a named subpattern, and the comment mode (`~x`) for more readability, but you can use instead the same pattern in a more compact version:

```
$pattern = '~"(?>[^"\\\]++|(?:\\\{2})++|\\\.)*"\K|[A-Z]++~';
```

*Unlike the nowdoc syntax, the backslash must be escaped twice.*